# keyboard shortcut to script as...CREATE TO...new query editor window

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been handed some legacy SQL Server 2005 database, and we have it running on SQL Server 2008 R2. There's a lot of reference to entities through inline SQL and no foreign keys, so I find myself repeatedly opening the T-SQL source of stored procs, which means going through the "script stored procedure as...CREATE to...new query editor window" GUI menu. Is there a way to bind this to a keyboard command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SSMS go to Tools -> Options and then see the screenshot for Ctrl + F1[image]

Basically I execute shortcut Ctrl + F1 in my case

Comment: Tried this but doesn't seem to do anything. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_name'
```

It will work for any "code" but not tables etc.

Comment: Attempting to view the stored procedure from the Object Explorer - To clarify you can hit F2 to highlight the selected Stored Procedure in Object explorer then hit CTRL N for an new query window and then paste in the name of the stored procedure and then use the sp_helptext keyboard shortcut to show the SP. Do you know of a faster way to view the SP when first selecting it from the Object explorer? The issue with this method is that you will only see the first 22 or so lines of the stored procedure and you will need another keyboard shortcut to scoll down. How do I do this without the mouse.

Comment: I usually just type in the name of the sp.  You can also drag it from the object explorer rather than hitting F2.  Or even right click on the object and go to script-create-new window.

Comment: Good call, I am a fan of finding keyboard shortcuts, so I don't have to switch to the mouse. Any ideas of the fastest way to a stored procedure view without the mouse?

Comment: I'm a big fan myself.  You know you can add your own right? https://sqlstudies.com/2015/07/06/adding-a-new-keyboard-shortcut-in-ssms/  For your case I would say just typing out the SP name .. or using dynamic SQL against sys.procedures.